# fading elements with iscroll and stellar

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch, fade, iscroll

I'm using stellar.js and iscroll.js for a parallax effect on a mobile page. That's working fine, so far.

But i'd like to fade the parallax elements with scrolling. iscroll has a onScrollMove event, which is triggered, as long as your finger is moving on the touchscreen. But during the animated "scrolling", when you don't touch the screen anymore, this event isn't triggered anymore.
So in this moment the scrolling, including parallax, is going on, but the fading stoped.

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve that problem?

Thanks for your help!